# Clion + WSL: "Nothing to run on"

Tags: c, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I think I set everything up correctly, I've looked at all of the Clion documentation related to this that I could find:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-clion.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html
- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/WSL+dev+environment+configuration

I followed each one to the best of my ability, but wasn't able to set up the debugger. I have all of the tools installed, I've tried on multiple projects, etc.

Main window:

[image: Main window]

Toolchains:

[image: Toolchains window]

Error window:

[image: Debug window]

Comment: Error window seems to be wrong caption for the last image?

Comment: I can see what you mean, fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't there be makefile with cmake commands how to make project executable names and so on. I don't know that clion can work without makefile.